# End HTML5 video loop with click anywhere on document

Tags: javascript, html, events, video, html5-video

I have a HTML5 video that I set to loop over a given interval, upon the push of a button.

The user should be able to exit the loop with a click anywhere in the document. The video should pause.

With my current code the click event registers only sporadically, or not at all.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <video src="./example.mp4" width="480" type="video/mp4" controls></video>
    <button>Test</button>
</body>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
    var timeStamp = [7, 8];

    video.addEventListener('canplay', execute);

    function execute() {
        video.removeEventListener('canplay', execute);
        $('button').click(function() {
            playVideoInterval(timeStamp[0], timeStamp[1]);
        });

        function playVideoInterval(start, end) {
            video.addEventListener('timeupdate', loop);
            video.currentTime = start;

            document.body.addEventListener('click', endLoop, true);
            video.play();

            function loop() {
                if (this.currentTime >= end) {
                    video.currentTime = start;
                    video.play();
                }
            }

            function endLoop() {
                video.pause();
                document.body.removeEventListener('click', endLoop);
                video.removeEventListener('timeupdate', loop);
                console.log('hi');

            }
        }    
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery, capture any click on document. Equivalent of what you were trying to do without JQuery. Make sure you set the class or id for the video player, then interact with it accordingly.

I used `event.stopPropagation();` for the button, and then a document event listener for the pause. I didn't have time to completely redo your code, restructure it.

This example will work in snippet.

```js
var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
var timeStamp = [7, 8];
var loop = false

function execute() {
    video.removeEventListener('canplay', execute);
    $('button').click(function() {
        playVideoInterval(timeStamp[0], timeStamp[1]);
    });

    function playVideoInterval(start, end) {
        video.addEventListener('timeupdate', loop);
        video.currentTime = start;

        document.body.addEventListener('click', endLoop, true);
        video.play();

        function loop() {
            if (this.currentTime >= end) {
                video.currentTime = start;
                video.play();
            }
        }

        function endLoop() {
            document.body.removeEventListener('click', endLoop);

            video.removeEventListener('timeupdate', loop);

            video.pause();

        }
    }
}

$(".play").on("click", function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    execute()

});

$(document).on("click", function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is('.play')) {
        // do something
        video.pause()
    }


});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <body>
      <video width="200" id="myVideo" height="150" autoplay controls>
         <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"  type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
  <button class="play" width="100px" height="100px" style="display:block; width:500px; height:100px;">Test</button>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I added it in with your code, to give you an idea. It works in snippet.

Comment: It still doesn't quite work... It will not register the click nor will it mesh well with my other event listeners

Comment: It is working 100% for me, in Chrome. What browser are you using? Your code works with my edit & mine. Did you run the snippet.

Comment: I added a button to your snippet to show my actual code functionality and the click will not let the button run a loop

Comment: One second, I am redoing your code locally. You didn't mention anything about a loop, I will add that.

Comment: it was my first sentence in my post... :)

Comment: I haven't forgot about you, I am working on it. Reading your code, and I will edit mine when its done. You want a button to loop, or the loop to start on document load. Or you want the button to do what exactly? EDIT: re-read I gotchu

Comment: I want the loop to begin when the user pushes the button, then have the loop exit when the user clicks anywhere on the document

Comment: There  you go sorry, my browser was freezing up for some reason. I edited it, check it now.

Comment: And remember, it won't autoplay in stack because of their settings. But I tested it, button runs a loop. Click anywhere it pauses.

Comment: Thanks! Helped me figure out a solution that worked -- I ended up assigning an intermediate class "looping" to the video and then checking for it in your document.on click function

Comment: Glad to help. Thank you